# JavaFX and Swing - High Frequency Update - Performance Comparison

Tags: java, performance, swing, javafx, comparison

I want to design a interface which has multiple control components (***maybe 60-70 components***). These components will show various **high-frequency(50hertz)** updated values. I don't want to be throttling on interface.

Which one should I prefer according to '***CPU utilization***', '***Memory usage***' or '***smooth actions***'?

I researched answer of this question on various platforms. But, I couldn't find a definitive answer for high-frequency statement.

Thank you for helps.

Comment: Memory usage is irrelevant.  Neither Swing nor JavaFX uses a lot of memory, even with 70 components in a window.

Comment: Recommendation: Try something. Your bottle neck will likely come down to how you sync the data to the ui, you’ll want to make this as smooth as possible (ie updating as many components as possible in a single pass)